# Desyncing android phone from google

Tags: google-account

We set up our daughters new phone using my husband google account. He turned off the sync for contacts on just her phone because she doesn’t need all his contacts. Several days later most of his contacts were deleted and ones that he had deleted off his phone were now back on his phone. How can he keep his contacts on his phone and not on our daughter phone

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is open a new account for your daughter. 
If you want your daughter to have access to apps puchased by your husband, have a read on how to share the apps with family here:
https://support.google.com/googleplay/search?hl=en&q=Family&from_promoted_search=true